# 'Count' múltiple en una sola consulta Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, count

Verán, tengo que llenar esta grafica.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como pueden ver es una grafica de 'CitasMedicas', y cada dato de cada especialidad representan el numero de citas medicas realizadas durante la semana. (Esta semana, La semana anterior, y la anterior a esa)

Lo de las fechas lo realice con Carbon. Mi problema ahora es con la consulta.
La tabla de la que extraeré los datos ('CitasMedicas') tiene registrado un medico, y este medico que esta asociado a una especialidad.

Lo que quiero hacer es una sola consulta, cuente, cuantas fichas hubieron para cada especialidad. El problema es que, hacerlo con `Count()` significaria hacer una consulta para cada Especialidad. Lo que seria muy tedioso e impractico.

```
$MedicinaGeneralMenosDos = DB::table('fichamedica')
    ->join('Medicos','fichamedica.Medico_ID','=','Medicos.ID')
    ->where('Medicos.Especialidad_ID','=',1)
    ->whereBetween('fecha',[$fechaMenosUnMes,$fecha_actual])
    ->count();
```

Algo así, pero para cada especialidad. Por lo que serian muchas consultas.
Otra solucion que pense fue hacer un get() que me devuelva solo las especialidades.

```
$MedicinaGeneralMenosDos = DB::table('fichamedica')
    ->join('Medicos','fichamedica.Medico_ID','=','Medicos.ID')
    ->join('Especialidades','Medicos.Especialidad_ID','=','Especialidades.ID')
    ->select('Especialidades.especialidad')
    ->whereBetween('fecha',[$fechaMenosUnaSemana,$fecha_actual])
    ->orderBy('Medicos.Especialidad_ID','Asc')
    ->get();
```

Algo así, esto me devolvería un array con las especialidades y contarlas por especialidad. Pero no se como podría hacer eso.
El problema es que son 12 especialidades y 3 rangos de fecha diferentes, por lo que si lo hago una por una terminaría haciendo 36 consultas.
Ayuda.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Lo de los rangos de fecha no son el problema. En si, para cada especialidad, tengo que hacer 3 consultas. Las citas de esta semana, la anterior y la anterior a esa. Pero esa parte ya la tengo solucionada. Mi problema es que no quiero hacer 12 `Count()`
Ya que debo hacer 1 count por cada especialidad para contar cuantas citas hubieron para Cardiologia, por ejemplo.

Comment: Podrias explicarme como por favor? Como meter el `count` dentro del `select`?

Comment: Tienes una tabla `Especialidades` en donde estan cada una de las especialidades, relacionada a las citas médicas, ¿verdad? creo que tal vez sea más fácil haciendo la consulta a esa tabla

Comment: Probablemente la solución de @BetaM sea buena, pero no logro entenderla del todo, disculpen

Comment: Listo, puse una foto de las tres tablas. En si la tabla ´fichamedica´ contiene un `medico` y este medico contiene una `especialidad`. Lo que quiero es contar cuantas fichas hay para Cada especialidad en un rango de fecha determinado. (Las fechas ya las tengo definidas en Variables, `fechaActual`, `UltimoLunes`,`semanaPasada`,`AnteSemanaPasada`. Con estas variables hago las consultas usando un whereBeetween.

Answer (score 1):

Bien, la solución que encontré fue la siguiente

```
 $MedicinaGeneralMenosDos = DB::table('fichamedica')
    ->join('Medicos','fichamedica.Medico_ID','=','Medicos.ID')
    ->join('Especialidades','Medicos.Especialidad_ID','=','Especialidades.ID')
    ->select('Especialidades.especialidad',DB::raw('count(*) as Fichas'))
    ->whereBetween('fecha',[$fechaMenosUnaSemana,$fecha_actual])
    ->orderBy('Medicos.Especialidad_ID','Asc')
    ->groupBy('Especialidades.especialidad')
    ->get();
```

Dentro del select, use `DB::raw()` para poder basicamente escribir instrucciones SQL sin procesar. Asi pues, dentro del `raw("count(*) as Fichas")` pude hacer un `count(*)` para hacer el conteo, y el `as Fichas` es el nombre del campo donde me devolvera los datos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me devolvió esto. (Actualmente solo tengo 4 citas)
Tambien pueden usar en lugar de count(*) un MAX, MIN... funciones de SqL. No se si todas, pero son varias ademas del count(*).